# etckeeper, Git checkout, and broken file permissions in /etc

Tags: git, file-permissions, etckeeper

I wanted to figure out why, after a [etckeeper](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/etckeeper/) commit, I had a problem with rebooting (already solved thanks to this great thing).

I played with etckeeper, did `git checkout some_commit_sha` for a quick look and then `git checkout master`.

And it seems my file permissions in `/etc` were broken after those manipulations. All files including `ssh_host_rsa_key passwd-, shadow-` were `rw-r--r--`. I didn't know Git does not save file permissions.

Now I fixed all of them (I hope I didn't miss anything).

What was the right way to get earlier states of `/etc`, look around, and go back to the master with the right file permissions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the documentation (see below) you have to run

```
etckeeper init
```

after checking any files back out in order to restore permissions.  git can't store file permissions directly so it's handled by etckeeper and you need to run the init again to restore them after a checkout.

Documentation section,

> You can use any git commands you like,
>   but do keep in mind that, if you check
>   out a different branch or an old
>   version, git is operating directly on
>   your system's /etc. If you do decide
>   to check out a branch or tag, make
>   sure you run "etckeeper init" again,
>   to get any metadata changes:
>
> git checkout april_first_joke_etc
>
> etckeeper init

Comment: This is good to know. He kind of had a two part question. The right way to "look around" and also the right way to restore the permissions. Wouldn't the right way to "look around" be to clone the /etc git repo to another directory and do diff and checkouts there until the root cause of his reboot troubles could be solved?